# No inline css, simple css file?

Tags: block-editor

I'm struggling HARD to simply adjust css.

Wordpress creates a lot of unneccessary inline css, with styles for every block of content. As of right now we’re up to ‘.wp-block-78’ or something like that, while I’d love to have a way of having no inline css, with a css file which has the properties for classes like h2 or custom classes. Is that possible? Thank you in advance!

As an example of what I'd love the html and css to look like I dug out this: https://www.styleshout.com/demo/?theme=augustine

Comment: what specifically are you trying to do or the problem you're trying to solve? I can't see any examples or code in your question and this appears to be a means to an end you haven't mentioned so there's little context. Use the edit link to adjust your question so that it's more specific with concrete examples of classes and blocks that can be reproduced directly. E.g. are you trying to change the colour of all H2's or apply some other styling to h2's on specific pages? Try to lead your question with your end goal to avoid X Y problem style questions

Comment: if you want to add a CSS file to add extra CSS rules can you modify your question to allow for that as an answer? Use the `Edit` link to do that

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the theme, but you should be able to target all h2s in content with a selector like `.entry-content h2`, or manually add classes and target those. (Just make sure to use a consistent class name.)

[image: edit an h2 class manually]

Comment: Thank you, but isn't there a way to edit the wordpress css file directly instead of creating extra classes?

Comment: @JeromeStephan the answer to that is not a simple yes/no/location of file, and can depend enormously on your theme and plugins. You also should never, ever under any circumstances make modifications to WordPress core files, many hosts will flag it as a hacking breach, and any updates to WordPress will destroy your changes. Your goal can be achieved without modifying the specific CSS files in WordPress, so ask how to achieve your goal, not how to implement a specific solution

Comment: @JeromeStephan like Tom is saying, it will not always be a good idea to edit even a theme CSS file, if that theme isn't one you maintain yourself. You mention a "css file used" in your original post — what is that?

Comment: It might be that I understood WP wrong, apparently WP does everything with inline css. To me, that sounds like very bad practice, and I'd love if you could tell me if there's a way to have a very minimal setup with no inline css and a simple css file which then has the properties for the classes. Thank you!

Comment: that's not true either, there's more than meets the eye, if you shared your actual goal what you want to achieve we can help. E.g. you don't need to make inline css or modify a CSS file that already exists, other options exist. If you're just asking "How do I add custom CSS to my site" that's a much simpler and easier question with a trivial answer, edit your question to make that clear rather than focusing on the mechanics of how you want to change things and it will become a lot easier

Comment: and yes, if you make a one off change to a single instance of a block it might put inline CSS if it thinks that it would be faster than a separate file, but that's only if you specifically choose to make a change to the styling of a block, and many sites don't use blocks or work that way. Lots of themes and plugins output CSS independently of WordPress or blocks too, both inline or via dedicated CSS files. Adding your own CSS file with your own custom changes is possible ( but you've worded your question in such a way that telling you how won't answer the question )

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Tom! I edited my question to clear it up. Tell me if I should give more details or if you have an answer!